# How to sustain (pedal) a note?

Tags: sound

I searched the documentation for `SoundNote`, `Sound`, `EmitSound`, etc... but cannot find any references to a "sustain" or "pedal" effect.

Does anyone know of how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You could try to code what you require as a MIDI file, then import it to get a `Sound` object.

Comment: @MarcoB that could work, but its really a dynamic effect, I'd have to prerecord every single possible sound I might want to sustain no?

Comment: Well, the way I understand it, sounds in *Mathematica* are essentially generated by specifying values of a waveform as a function of time. You are then left with the typical problem of synthesizer/filter designers, i.e. how to simulate the effect of a physical phenomenon (e.g. reverb, echo, sustain, distortion) on a waveform. I can't imagine that there could be a cookie-cutter definition of a "Sustain" effect in this context. In short, it is my opinion that you would have to develop your own filter to achieve that effect.

Comment: If the question is to sustain (pedal) 'a note' ... as in a single note ... what would be the difference between holding the pedal vs increasing the duration of the note?  With multiple notes held (and new ones being played on top), things get more interesting with harmonics and such ... This may be even the case with a single note being played (since ALL the strings are not damped while the pedal is pressed ... so they all resonate) ... but it does not seem to me that you are asking a question about the subtleties of harmonics?? Or are you?

Answer (score 4):

This may depend on how MIDI is implemented on your system, but on my system (Windows 8.1) the following works to get a sustain pedal working.

It plays a note for 48/96 (0.5) seconds with the sustain pedal pressed at t = 5/96 s and the sustain pedal released at `sus/96` seconds.

```
sus=50; (* try sus=500 for a long sustain *)

Sound`EmitMIDI[
   Sound`MIDISequence[
     {
        Sound`MIDITrack[
          {
            Sound`MIDIEvent[0, "SetTempo", "Tempo" -> 1000000], 
            Sound`MIDIEvent[
               0, "ControlCommand", "Channel" -> 0,
               "Controller" -> "CoarseBankSelect", "Value" -> 1
            ], 
            Sound`MIDIEvent[
               0, "ControlCommand", "Channel" -> 0, 
               "Controller" -> "FineBankSelect", "Value" -> 1
            ], 
            Sound`MIDIEvent[0, "ProgramCommand", "Channel" -> 0, "Value" -> 5],         
            Sound`MIDIEvent[0, "NoteOn", "Note" -> 67, "Channel" -> 0, "Velocity" -> 127],
            Sound`MIDIEvent[
               5, "ControlCommand", "Channel" -> 0, 
               "Controller" -> 64, "Value" -> 100
            ],  (* sustain pedal (control change nr 64) on *)            
            Sound`MIDIEvent[48, "NoteOff", "Note" -> 67, "Channel" -> 0, "Velocity" -> 0],
            Sound`MIDIEvent[
               sus, "ControlCommand", "Channel" -> 0, 
               "Controller" -> 64, "Value" -> 0]
            (* sustain pedal off *)
          }
        ]
     }, 
     "DivisionType" -> "PPQ", "Resolution" -> 96
  ]
]
```

Comment: Nice solution. But how can I combine this as a note in a sequence via Sound? As in `Sound[{SoundNote["c3", {0, 1}], SoundNote[pedal["e3"], {3, 4}], SoundNote["g3", {2, 3}]}]`. I'd like to not have to manually set the start and end times. Is there somewhere I can read about Sound`* symbols?